# how to if else to show something else laravel

Tags: php, html, mysql, database, laravel

my view page:

```html
@if(empty($data))
  <p>No response have been attached to this entities.</p>
@else
  <p>By default, it will respond with the predefined phrases. Use the form below to customize responses.</p>
@endif
```

controller:

```html
public function queries($companyID, $entityType, $entityValue)
 {
  $data = [];

  $details = DiraQuestion::where('company_id', $companyID)->where('eType', $entityType)->where('eVal', $entityValue)->get();
  
  foreach ($details AS $datum) 
  { 
   if (!isset($data[$datum->intent])) $data[$datum->intent] = ['question' => [], 'answer' => []]; 
   $data[$datum->intent]['question'][$datum->queries] = $datum->id; 
  } 

  $detailsAns = DiraResponses::where('company_id', $companyID)->where('eType', $entityType)->where('eVal', $entityValue)->get();
  
  foreach ($detailsAns AS $datum) 
  { 
   if (!isset($data[$datum->intent])) $data[$datum->intent] = ['question' => [], 'answer' => []]; 
   $data[$datum->intent]['answer'][$datum->reply] = $datum->id; 
  }

  ksort($data);
  return view('AltHr.Chatbot.queries', compact('data','entityType','entityValue','companyID'));
 }
```

I made the controller and view shown above, but I can't seem to figure out what the problem is when there is no data it still shows like this:

[image]

I am trying to have it show the data but when there isn't data then for it to show something else.

I have two examples of with and without data when I dd();

first with data:

[image: with]

second without data:

[image: without]

so the one without data should shows something else like an error message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$data` is not empty in both cases, you need to be checking the `answer` index:

```
@if(empty($data['answer']))
  <p>No response have been attached to this entities.</p>
@else
  <p>By default, it will respond with the predefined phrases. Use the form below to customize responses.</p>
@endif
```

**edit**

You've also got an empty string index wrapping both `answer` and `question` so

```
@if(empty($data['']['answer']))
```

Comment: i also did this way, it still doesnt work, with this way it shows me "<p>No response have been attached to this entities.</p>" with data and without data

Comment: I've edited my answer, you have an empty string index before both

Comment: still the same thing happening as i mention above

Comment: what is the purpose of `$datum->intent`?

Answer (score 0):

because you use empty() function to check data,but in controller $data is array, so It always not empty.
You can change empty() function to count() function. If $data is empty or null, it will be equal zero.

```html
@if(count($data)==0)
<p>No response have been attached to this entities.</p>
@else
  <p>By default, it will respond with the predefined phrases. Use the form below to customize responses.</p>
@endif
```